# Пишу нейросеть которая распознает изображения. Есть 2 вопроса!

Tags: python-3.x

Здраствуйте, пишу нейросеть которая распознает изображения. Есть 2 вопроса!

Итак, 1:
 Как лучше всего указать пиксель числом (PIL дает цвет по RGB (255,255,255) ), а хотелось-бы или по яркости (от 0 до 255), или каким-то другим способом!

И 2 вопрос:
 Допустим мы смогли изображения вывести в список значений (цифр), но тут следуящая проблема - если у нас изображение 500х500 пикселей то длина списка (500*500) - 250000 пикелей!!! Если такое подать на вход нейросети, то она будет пахать целую вечность! Нужно как-то "сжать изображение" с сохранением основных признаков, ДПФ(дискретное преобразование Фурье) - не помогает, потому что длина входного и выходного списка одинакова! А нам надо уменьшить длину!

Спасибо за внимание! Надеюсь мне помогут!))

Comment: Мне кажется, всё будет сильно зависеть от конкретной задачи. Надо просто пробовать.

Comment: Если бы знать что пробывать, и как!)

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте,
1) используйте серую палитру. Советую провести преобразование по алгоритму анализа гистограммы.
2) Для этого нужно делить изображение на блоки, размер которых в k раз меньше размера того, что вы ищете. (k зависит от того, что вы ищете). И берите какую-то функцию от блока, есть много таких операторов, тоже зависит от того, что вы ищете), получаете меньшую матрицу.
Невозможность улучшения 1) состоит в том, что вы хотите из 256^3 -> 256 значениям, поэтому будет потеря инфы.
А 2) это известный способ. Про него можно прочитать на хабре.

Comment: Вы предлагаете преобразовывать изображение в серую палитру, а потом уменьшать количество пикселей преобразованием по алгоритму анализа гистограммы?

Comment: Я так понял что для таких больших изображений без СНС(Сверточных Нейронных Сетей) не обойтись. :)